# TIBCO BW 5 Read Excel file

Tags: excel, tibco

I would ask you if is there some way to read an excel file(.xls) using TIBCO BW 5.

Till now I'm made this in three different ways:

1: As convert excel file(.xls) to CSV file.

2: As .xls as an XML file

3: As custom Java code, that reads Excel files, using Apache library(Poi)

Unfortunately, there is no Excel plug-in for TIBCO BW 5. Or I cannot find it :(

Another way that I found, is that I could use Windows ODBC -  everything is configured, but after I add the rt.jar file, still can not make a connection with TIBCO Designer.

Every time It throws this exception:

<[image]>

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

On TIBCO BW 5.X projects the following solutions are commonly used:

1: Convert excel file(.xls) to CSV file.
3: Custom Java code, that reads Excel files, using Apache library(Poi)

In a BusinessWorks 6.X context you can use the EXCEL plugin that is using the apache POI library.

Answer (score 0):

you need place that odbc jar in your Tibco_Home\tpcl\5.11\jdbc.
restart the designer.

**Note:-if there is no jdbc folder create it**

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately, there is no Excel plug-in for TIBCO BW 5. Or I cannot find it :(

It's there: https://docs.tibco.com/products/tibco-activematrix-businessworks-plug-in-for-microsoft-excel-6-1-1

Once you import the Excel plug-in into your project, you could simply use the "Excel Read" activity, passing the excel file you want to read. The plugin also provides you a lot of other excel-related functions.